# Is it possible to avoid persisting of subclass with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I know you can ignore fields with @Transient annotation. I cannot find the way to denote that I don't want specific subclass to be persisted in database. Here are model classes:

Element class:

```
@Entity
public class Element {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<String, Base> map;

    private String text;

}
```

Base class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    Long id;

    String type;
}
```

Foo class:

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends  Base {

    boolean flag;
}
```

Bar class:

```
@Entity
public class Bar extends Base {

    int number;

}
```

Test object persisted:

```
Map<String, Base> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("foo-1" , new Foo());
map1.put("bar-1" , new Bar());
repo.save(new Element("element-1" , map1));
```

Table generated:

```
element table:
+------+-----------+
| id   | text      |
|------+-----------|
| 1    | element-1 |
+------+-----------+

element_map table;
+--------------+----------+-----------+
| element_id   | map_id   | map_key   |
|--------------+----------+-----------|
| 1            | 1        | bar-1     |
| 1            | 2        | foo-1     |
+--------------+----------+-----------+

base table:
+------+--------+
| id   | type   |
|------+--------|
| 1    | <null> |
| 2    | <null> |
+------+--------+

foo table:
+--------+------+
| flag   | id   |
|--------+------|
| False  | 2    |
+--------+------+

bar table:
+----------+------+
| number   | id   |
|----------+------|
| 0        | 1    |
+----------+------+
```

Is it possible to configure JPA to ignore Bar class and do NOT persist it in DB?

I tried adding @Transient annotation to all fields in `Bar` class but I end up with a `bar` table generated with only one field `id` inherited from the `Base` class. I would like to avoid having useless table database.

I tried removing @Entity annotation from `Bar` class but I end up with an exception each time a `Bar` object is persisted:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [ch.smooth.hibernateinheritancehashmap.Bar] expected instance/subclass of [ch.smooth.hibernateinheritancehashmap.Base]; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [ch.smooth.hibernateinheritancehashmap.Bar] expected instance/subclass of [ch.smooth.hibernateinheritancehashmap.Base]
```

Any ideas how to specify part of class hierarchy to be transient?

I've isolated the problem for easier reproduction in a small spring-boot application on github: https://github.com/gladky/jpa-persistence-issue. Running mvn install will yield the exception which I mentioned.

Comment: I just did a test and when I remove the Entity annotation on Bar then everything works as expected. Do you may have the Bar class listed in a persistence.xml?

Comment: @Simon, thank you for reply. Yes, I tried removing Bar from persistence.xml. The exception is thrown when an object Element containing object Bar in the map is persisted. Another test I did was using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa without persistence.xml (purely annotation driven). In both setups the exception was thrown on persist attempt (the application starts without any problems). I've isolated the problem for easier reproduction in a small spring-boot application on github: https://github.com/gladky/jpa-persistence-issue. Running mvn install will yield the exception which I mentioned.